# How to store a child class in a property of the parent class?

Tags: php, inheritance, parent-child

It seems quite simple but I'm not getting it done for quite a while now...

```
class Main
{
    public $sub1;
    public $sub2;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sub1 = new Sub1();
        $this->sub2 = new Sub2();
    }
}

class Sub1 extends Main
{
    public function __construct() {}

    public function helloWorld()
    {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}

class Sub2 extends Main
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sub1->helloWorld();
    }
}

new Main();
```

The result of the code is **Fatal error: Call to a member function helloWorld()**. But why? I don't understand why the sub1 property of the Main class is NULL when I try to access it from sub2. Could anyone please explain it to me? Am I doing something basically wrong in terms of OOP programming? Am I hurting any concepts? Are there any better solutions?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding Main's `__construct()` in both Sub1 and Sub2, meaning Main's construct is never called. Even if you were to call `parent::__construct()` in Sub1 and Sub2's construct, you would get an infinite loop because Main's construct is initializing both subs.

**Edit:** Since you want to share objects, here are a couple SO questions that can help: 
[Sharing objects between PHP classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819334/sharing-objects-between-php-classes) 
[How to create an object in a parent class shared by its children classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889319/how-to-create-an-object-in-a-parent-class-shared-by-its-children-classes)

Comment: Thank you. Now I even understood why the constructor is called in a static context (:

Answer (score 0):

How can you expect you not to be fatal. You are trying to access $Sub1 without having an instance of it. What you need to understand is the instantiation of objects. When you are writing a class, it is just definition. You need an instance to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can explain what problem you're trying to solve, obviously you can't do it in this way, but I'm guessing your problem shouldnt be depend on solution which you come with.
So maybe someone can have a good answer for you.